What runs the DHCP client on Android?
I am building AOSP (version 14) from sources, for a PinePhone (so I have root access). I am trying to get reverse tethering to work (i.e. the Android device connects to the network through the other device over Ethernet).
I can plug an Ethernet-over-usb adapter and see that a new network interface (eth0) appears in the output of ip link. This interface eth0 is <UP> but has state DOWN. It never gets in state UP and it never gets an IP.
In this situation on a Linux distro, I would just run a DHCP client for this interface. But on AOSP, I don't have a DHCP client to run from the command line (dhcpcd is no longer used in recent versions of Android, if I understand correctly).

Is there a way to manually run a DHCP server from the CLI?
What mechanism is supposed to handle this? On some phones and under some conditions (e.g. "the WiFi is not connected"), then plugging an Ethernet cable into the Android device "just works". What should I do in my AOSP build to make this "just work" for all eth* interfaces that may appear?


See NETWORK CONFIGURATION in How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?.

Wow that's a great answer! I think the conclusion is that after eth* appears, then Android is probably trying to get an IP, and something else may be wrong. I see NO_CARRIER appear with my interface, which suggests (I guess?) that the other side is not behaving properly? Not sure when NO_CARRIER disappears exactly (yet).
